# which one is correct "Let this process to be completed"

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice, infinitives

Which one is correct?

> 1. **Let** this process **to be completed**.

or

> 2. **Let** this process **to complete**.

Comment: I suggest specifying the context in which the phrases would appear.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatically incorrect.

Please look at the following imperative  sentence in the active voice:

Complete this process.

You use the pattern "let + object + be + past participle"
to change such sentences in the passive voice as follows:

Let this process be completed.

You never use to-infinitive when you use let in the active voice or passive voice; you use the bare infinitive in the active voice and be + past participle in the passive.  For examples:

Let him complete this process.

let this process be completed by him.

Let me write a letter.

Let a letter be written by me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the word "Allow" instead of the word "Let", both sentences would be correct:

> 1b. **Allow** this process **to be completed**.
>   2b. **Allow** this process **to complete**.

Answer (score 0):

Neither!

Go for...

> Let this process complete.

The verb *'let'* is a magical verb. Here, the subject *does not do direct action* by itself and thus, you won't find even ''s' for the third person verbs.

> He completes something **BUT** Let him <del>to</del> complete something

The use of 'let' in **such context** takes no 'to' or 'to be'. You are not *letting* the process **to do something**.

Another way is...

> Let this process *get* completed